# Sentiment Analysis - What does annotating dataset mean?

Tags: annotations, dataset, nlp, stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis

I'm currently working on my final year research project, which is an application which analyzes travel reviews found online, and give out a sentiment score for particular tourist attractions as a result, by conducting aspect level sentiment analysis.

I have a newly scraped dataset from a famous travel website which does not allow to use their API for research/academic purposes. (bummer)

My supervisor said that I might need to get this dataset annotated before using it for the aforementioned purpose. I am kind of confused as to what data annotation means in this context. Could someone please explain what exactly is happening when a dataset is annotated and how it helps in getting sentiment analysis done?

I was told that I might have to get two/three human annotators and get the data annotated to make it less biased. I'm on a tight schedule and I was wondering if there are any tools that can get it done for me? If so, what will be the impact of using such tools over human annotators? I would also like suggestions for such tools that you would recommend.

I would really appreciate a detailed explanation to my questions, as I am stuck with my project progressing to the next step because of this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To a first approximation, machine learning algorithms (e.g., a sentiment analysis algorithm) is learning to perform a task that humans currently perform by collecting many examples of the human performing the task, and then imitating them. When your supervisor talks about "annotation," they're talking about collecting these examples of a human doing the sentiment annotation task: annotating a sentence for sentiment. That is, collecting pairs of sentences and their sentiment as judged by humans. Without this, there's nothing for the program to learn from, and you're stuck hoping the program can give you something from nothing -- which it never will.

That said, there are tools for collecting this sort of data, or at least helping. Amazon Mechanical Turk and other crowdsourcing platforms are good resources for this sort of data collection. You can also take a look at something like: http://www.crowdflower.com/type-sentiment-analysis.